# Is it possible to kill other nodes in launch file when a particular one ends/dies?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a situation where I'd like to kill all other nodes launched from the same launch file once another is finished doing its work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10089/is-it-possible-to-kill-other-nodes-in-launch-file-when-a-particular-one-ends/dies?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you want the `required="true"` parameter for your node element. http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node says: "If node dies, kill entire roslaunch."

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-27**:
Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for.